# JSON Stringer For android

Tags: android

How to pass an array to `JSON` string?

```
JSONStringer jsonStringer = new JSONStringer().object.key("key").value(value).key("key").array().value(arrayvalue).endArray().endObject
```

My problem is how can I pass arrayvalue here?

The value is:

> "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"..... "item100"

How can I do this?

Comment: you want to add this array string to JSON? Is that what you are asking

Comment: hi plz send me hall string of json

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the GSON library](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), I believe it will have what you need to easily solve this.